# What wrong with LoadIncrementalHFile?

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, hbase

I was a rookie about hadoop&Hbase . I want to import .csv file to Hfile.
I have a csv file "testcsv.csv" in HDFS

```
ty,12,1

tes,13,1

tt,14,1

yu,15,1

ui,16,1

qq,17,1
```

I use command in Masternode.

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv '-Dimporttsv.separator=,' -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,basic:G1,basic:G2, testTSV /user/hadoop/csvtest.csv
```

I verify Hbase table.

```
hbase(main):002:0> scan 'testTSV'
ROW                            COLUMN+CELL
 qq                            column=basic:G1, timestamp=1435682234304, value=17
 qq                            column=basic:G2, timestamp=1435682234304, value=1
 tes                           column=basic:G1, timestamp=1435682234304, value=13
 tes                           column=basic:G2, timestamp=1435682234304, value=1
 tt                            column=basic:G1, timestamp=1435682234304, value=14
 tt                            column=basic:G2, timestamp=1435682234304, value=1
 ty                            column=basic:G1, timestamp=1435682234304, value=12
 ty                            column=basic:G2, timestamp=1435682234304, value=1
 ui                            column=basic:G1, timestamp=1435682234304, value=16
 ui                            column=basic:G2, timestamp=1435682234304, value=1
 yu                            column=basic:G1, timestamp=1435682234304, value=15
 yu                            column=basic:G2, timestamp=1435682234304, value=1
6 row(s) in 1.6180 seconds
```

After that, I use CompleteBulkLoad methods, to load data from StoreFile to table.

This command

```
  hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles /user/hadoop/outputfile testTSV
```

........................................................

```
2015-07-01 00:53:10,128 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/home/hadoop/app/lib
2015-07-01 00:53:10,128 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2015-07-01 00:53:10,128 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2015-07-01 00:53:10,128 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
2015-07-01 00:53:10,128 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
2015-07-01 00:53:10,128 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64
2015-07-01 00:53:10,128 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=hadoop
2015-07-01 00:53:10,128 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/hadoop
2015-07-01 00:53:10,128 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/hadoop/Hbase
2015-07-01 00:53:10,131 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=Datanode01:2181,Masternode01:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x526b00740x0, quorum=Datanode01:2181,Masternode01:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
2015-07-01 00:53:10,300 INFO  [main-SendThread(Datanode01:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server Datanode01/192.168.23.152:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-07-01 00:53:10,333 INFO  [main-SendThread(Datanode01:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to Datanode01/192.168.23.152:2181, initiating session
2015-07-01 00:53:10,358 INFO  [main-SendThread(Datanode01:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server Datanode01/192.168.23.152:2181, sessionid = 0x14e35637b2c000d, negotiated timeout = 90000
2015-07-01 00:53:12,901 INFO  [main] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Process identifier=hconnection-0x7d83bb5e connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=Datanode01:2181,Masternode01:2181
2015-07-01 00:53:12,901 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=Datanode01:2181,Masternode01:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x7d83bb5e0x0, quorum=Datanode01:2181,Masternode01:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
2015-07-01 00:53:12,905 INFO  [main-SendThread(Datanode01:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server Datanode01/192.168.23.152:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-07-01 00:53:12,906 INFO  [main-SendThread(Datanode01:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to Datanode01/192.168.23.152:2181, initiating session
2015-07-01 00:53:12,922 INFO  [main-SendThread(Datanode01:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server Datanode01/192.168.23.152:2181, sessionid = 0x14e35637b2c000e, negotiated timeout = 90000
2015-07-01 00:53:13,036 INFO  [main] client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closing zookeeper sessionid=0x14e35637b2c000e
2015-07-01 00:53:13,054 INFO  [main-EventThread] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
2015-07-01 00:53:13,054 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x14e35637b2c000e closed
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Bulkload dir /user/hadoop/outputfile not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.visitBulkHFiles(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:176)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.discoverLoadQueue(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:260)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.doBulkLoad(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:314)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.run(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:960)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.main(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:967)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are running ImportTSV command , it is looking into local filesystem to load csv file into HBase but in case of LoadIncrementalHFiles , it is looking for hfiles present into hdfs.I believ which is not there in you case.

Please verify if /user/hadoop/outputfile contains your hfiles in hdfs file system.

Answer (score 0):

The following clearly says, that the file is missing

```
FileNotFoundException: Bulkload dir /user/hadoop/outputfile not found
```

May be there no file by name outputfile. Its the relative path of the HFiles, which should be mentioned in your first command using ImportTsv. Please verify the directory

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a permissions issue when using the MapReduce tools.

If you add the param `-Dfs.permissions.umask-mode=000` when executing the mapreduce command, for instance:

`org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv`
or
`org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.CsvBulkLoadTool`

it will enable to write temporary files and the job will end successfully.

**Reference:**
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Phoenix-Bulk-Load-on-Ctrl-A-delimiter-error-code-143/m-p/154855/highlight/true#M117294